# Class design in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm struggling to implement some class design in TypeScript considering that it doesn't support multiple constructors with different prototypes.
Basically, I would like to design classes with a public constructor that takes some parameters, and an 'internal' constructor (only used within the library). The public constructor would call the internal one. In C#, it would look like this:

```
public class Class1
{
    internal Class1(int id)
    { 
    }

    public Class1(string s)
        : this(s.Length)
    {
    }
}
```

Any idea how I would translate this to TypeScript?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't really make internal/private constructors in TypeScript because of the way constructor functions work in JavaScript. Can you talk more about your use case? Would having an exposed `interface` and factory methods on a containing module be an acceptable solution?

Comment: I should indeed explain my use case. I'm trying to bridge an AS3 API from a SWF to JS. So I'm replicating the AS3 class hierarchy in JS and need 2 constructors for each class:
- one that has the same signature as its AS3 counterpart and will be called be the client code ; this will instantiate the AS3 class and store an ID in the JS object for future reference,
- one that takes an ID as parameter in the case where I need to return a JS object for an existing AS3 object (like when you get a class property that is itself an object -> not instantiated by the user but already existing in the AS3)

Comment: So are you writing TypeScript code as an intermediary, or do you just need a definition of the existing API so you can call it from TypeScript?

Comment: The TypeScript code would be the intermediary for client JS code willing to access the SWF functionalities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works as well, and is perhaps closer to the original:

```
class Class1 {

    id:number;

    constructor(s: string) {
        (n:number) => {
            this.id = n;
        }(s.length)
    }
}

var t:Class1 = new Class1("HELLO");
console.log("Class1ID: " + t.id); // Output = Class1 ID: 5
```

For reference, here's the output JS:

```
var Class1 = (function () {
    function Class1(s) {
        var _this = this;
        (function (n) {
            _this.id = n;
        })(s.length);
    }
    return Class1;
})();
var t = new Class1("HELLO");
console.log("Class1 ID: " + t.id);
```

**Update**

If you have to be able to call the constructor with just an ID, then I think you'll have to use a factory method, as Steve has suggested. And, since I don't think TS constructors can be private, if you need that method to be private you'll have to dispense with the constructor altogether and use a pair of factory methods. The first instance might look something like this:

```
class Class1 {

    constructor(public id:number) {} // Public, unfortunately.

    static Fabricate(s:string):Class1 {
        return new Class1(s.length);
    }
}

var classA:Class1 = new Class1(1);
var classB:Class1 = Class1.Fabricate("Hello");

console.log(classA.id);   // "1"
console.log(classB.id);   // "5"
```

And the second something like this:

```
class Class1 {

    id:number;

    private static fabricate(n:number):Class1 {
        var class1:Class1 = new Class1();
        class1.id = n;
        return class1;
    }

    static Fabricate(s:string):Class1 {
        return fabricate(s.length);
    }
}

var classA:Class1 = Class1.Fabricate("Hello");

console.log(classA.id);   // "5"
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but you cannot instantiate the class by passing the id only.

Comment: No, that's true - I only saw your comment on Steve's post above after I had added this answer. What this does give you is the other half of your problem: a private constructor that is called automatically when (but only when) the parent one is invoked.

Comment: I accepted your answer as this is probably the closest to what I want to achieve, considering TypeScript's constraints. Thanks anyway to all of you, it was very helpful.

Comment: Just to add that, while you can't make a constructor private, you can still avoid using a constructor by mistake by having it take a parameter of a non visibile type. For example, if you declare an interface that you don't export and have the public constructor accept a single parameter of that interface, then it's quite clear not to use it, and typescript will give you error if you try. Obviously, it can be circumvented (by using <any>{} for example), and you can check and throw exception inside the constructor, but still the result is quite similar : a yet visible but not usable constructor.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought was to use overloads, but this doesn't handle your protection of the numeric constructor, it would also mean adding a condition in the constructor to work out which parameter you were passed:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(s: number);
    constructor(s: string);
    constructor(s: any) {

    }
}
```

So the pragmatic solution would be to have a private function:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(s: string) {
        this.initialize(s.length);
    }

    private initialize(id: number) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But your solution doesn't allow the private (actually, internal) constructor to be called directly without passing through the public one (which is a requirement that I should have mentioned).

Comment: You could add a private static method that returns you a new instance.

Comment: Could this static method instantiate the class without calling the constructor with a string parameter?

Comment: @ThomasWeiss - no, the constructor is always going to be called. Indeed, TS type safety won't let you create `new Class1();` it will need to be `new Class1("some-string")`

Comment: You could make it optional: `constructor(s?: string)` - this would allow the constructor to be called with or without a string. You would need to check the argument was passed before attempting to access its length.

Comment: +1 in fairness as I don't think mine is necessarily a better answer.

Comment: Very fair indeed! Back at you!

Answer (score 0):

With TypeScript 1.4 Union types are now available to allow function type overloading. See the description from the [TypeScript Blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/01/16/announcing-typescript-1-4.aspx). This should allow you to have multiple constructor input types with one constructor function.

> ### Union Types
>
> JavaScript functions may take a number of possible argument types. Up to now, we’ve supported this using function overloads. Starting with TypeScript 1.4, we’ve generalized this capability and now allow you to specify that that a value is one of a number of different types using a union type:

```
function f(x: number | number[]) {
  if (typeof x === "number") {
    return x + 10;
  }
  else {
    // return sum of numbers
  }
}
```

> Once you have a value of a union type, you can use a typeof and instanceof checks to use the value in a type-safe way. You'll notice we use this in the above example and can treat x as a number type inside of the if-block.
>
> Union types are a new kind of type and work any place you specify a
>   type.